# Tags in the dupehammer tooltip are nearly impossible to see

Tags: bug, design, dupehammer, tooltips

Today I noticed this:
[image: dupehammer tooltip]

The tag in the dupehammer tooltip is is nearly impossible to see. Can the font colour be changed?

Comment: This appears to be in part because of the styling used on tags on this site. [tex.se] also has this problem because of simplistic styling of tags (see [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/mZgwI.png)), but [so] has more complex styles for displaying tags, and their dupehammer tooltips are easy to read (see [this image](http://i.stack.imgur.com/IkfFE.png)).